# Hooks Callback- react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I'm currently building a react app which has a component slider and I need to pass the data back to the parent, the only fact is that the child is a little bit complex hook and I've been unable to find something similar that can help me to implement on my project, this is what I have:

The child

```
function valuetext(value) {
  return `${value}`;
}

export default function RangeSlider() {
  const classes = useStyles();
  const [value, setValue] = React.useState([0, 100000]);

  const handleChange = (event, newValue) => {
    var val = setValue(newValue);
    //I guess here is when I'm suposed to send the info to the parent
  };

  return (
    <div className={classes.root}>
      <Typography id="range-slider" gutterBottom>
        Kilometers
      </Typography>
      <Slider
        value={value}
        max={500000}
        min={0}
        step={1000}
        onChange={handleChange}
        valueLabelDisplay="auto"
        aria-labelledby="range-slider"
        getAriaValueText={valuetext}
      />
      <div id="seats-labes">
        <span>0km</span>
        <span>50.0000km</span>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

The parent:

```
 function WebFilter(props) { 

    
    return (
        <div className="filter-web-section">
         
        <Accordion className="filter-accordion">
            <Card className="card-section">
                <Card.Body>
                    <RangeSlider/>
                </Card.Body>
            </Card>
        </Accordion>
    </div>
    )
}


export default WebFilter;
```

The grandfather:

```
class ResultModel extends Component {

    render() {
    
        return (
            <div>
                <h1>Texto de prueba + boton</h1> <button>+</button>
                <div className="SiteHeader">
                    <Header/>
                </div>
                <div className="cars-result-content">
                    <div className="cars-result-content__filters">
                        <WebFilter
                        />
                    </div>
                    <div className="car-result-content-list">
                        <div className="car-result-list__counter-cars">
                            <p>400 vehicles</p>
                        </div>
                        <div className="car-result-content-list__statBar">
                            <StatBar/>
                        </div>
                        <div className="cars-result-page-list__ListCars">
                            <ResultsView/>
                        </div>
                    </div>   
                </div>        
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

I've been reading about declaring the hook constants at the very first component (grandfather) but I haven't been able to find a way to pass the data through the father. Thanks in advance for any hint or help.

Comment: What's a "double-callback"?

Comment: Just have the grandparent pass prop to its child (parent), and the parent pass props to its child.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question is a bit short on specifics, but from what I can gather, you just need to pass down a function from component 1 through component 2 to component 3.

It's pretty straightforward actually.

In your grandpa component, create a function you want to pass:

```
class ResultModel extends Component {
   const func1 = (data) => {console.log(data)}

  render() {
    ...
```

Pass it down to father:

```
...
<WebFilter func1={func1} />
...
```

In the father component, get `func1` and pass it down to child:

```
function WebFilter(props) { 
    const {func1} = props;
    
    return (
        <div className="filter-web-section">
         
        <Accordion className="filter-accordion">
            <Card className="card-section">
                <Card.Body>
                    <RangeSlider func1={func1} />
                </Card.Body>
            </Card>
        </Accordion>
    </div>
    )
}
```

Then in child call it like so:

```
export default function RangeSlider({func1}) {
  const classes = useStyles();
  const [value, setValue] = React.useState([0, 100000]);

  const handleChange = (event, newValue) => {
    var val = setValue(newValue);
    //I guess here is when I'm suposed to send the info to the parent
    func1("your data")
  };
...
...
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, always I try this method I keep getting `TypeError: func1 is not a function` error.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to learn something read about react concept called `lifting the state up`.

Read about lifting state up in react [documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html)

Or just google it read one or two articles if still don't get it then post a comment I'll write full code.